# Can you enter a constraint value with decimal in IB?

Tags: storyboard, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Here is to hoping it is a simple setting.

I cannot enter a constraint value with decimals in IB. Whenever I enter a value with decimals and press enter, the system rounds it!

I don't have this problem when creating constraints in code. Only in IB.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 30):

Yes, you can.

1. Enter the value with a "f" postfix like this:
   [image]
2. Click Priority. notice how the effective constraint value changes to 0.5:
   [image]
3. Hit ESC

Comment: In Xcode 7 rounds to 0, looks like most reliable way is to set it in code

Comment: This is tested and working on Xcode 7.3.1. Make sure you follow the instructions accurately, as weird as it may look.

Comment: This is weird but it is also working in Xcode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a)

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Xcode 8.3. "0.5f" is replaced with ",5" when I hit enter and then with 0 when the text field loses focus.

Comment: it works on xcode 8.3.2, as @AmitP says make sure you follow the instruction

Comment: I try this method. While it shows `.5`, I try `.9` so it should be more obvious, it still not show up on the screen. Anyone?

Comment: Works in Xcode 9.2. One little detail: regardless of what is decimal point character on your machine, you should use dot character e.g. "0.5", even though proper character for my language is comma :)

Comment: It worked (Xcode 9.4.1), but only after I changed Region to the country in which dot (.) is used for decimal in System Preferences / Language & Region.

Answer (score 7):

It has to be done programmatically, I believe. As of Xcode 6.3, constraint constant values seem to be restricted to integers in the storyboard editor (unlike multiplier values, which can be decimals).

*For Googlers, here's how to do it:*

To specify a decimal value for a constraint defined in a storyboard, you can set the constant property of a constraint iVar. Here's an example of setting a height constraint to 0.5f:

**In your header:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *separatorHeightConstraint;
```

then connect the IBOutlet to the constraint in the storyboard.

**In your implementation:**

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.separatorHeightConstraint.constant = 0.5f;
}
```

That's all!

Comment: That would change the `constant` of the constraint every time the view layouts its views (lots of times). The `constant` should only be set once and then it will redraw automatically on `layoutSubviews`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Setting a constant doesn't trigger a layout.  Apple's documentation says: "Override the viewWillLayoutSubviews or layoutSubviews methods to modify the results returned by the layout engine."  [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ModifyingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH29-SW4)

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong. I meant you should call `constraint.constant=value;` **once** and then call `[self.view setNeedsLayout];` and let the layout system do its thing. Why re-set the value on every layout cycle?

Comment: Gotcha. This question is from a few years ago, but I think at the time, setting a decimal constraint elsewhere (and then calling `setNeedsLayout`) caused the constraint to get rounded up to 1.0f sometime before `layoutSubviews` was called again.  I haven't tried this lately since it's possible to set a fractional constraint less than 1.0f in a storyboard these days without any issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to set constant decimal value in storyboard that is not dependent on screen scale, you can use `user defined runtime attributes`, for example for constraint constant it would be:

Key Path: `constant`
Type: `Number`
Value: `0,5`

---

If you want to make a delimiter by making a view with 1-pixel width on @2x and @3x devices you can use a constraint that sets view's width/height and set its class to your own constraint subclass. Example of such subclass:
OnePixelWidthConstraint.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OnePixelWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint
@end
```

OnePixelWidthConstraint.m:

```
#import "OnePixelWidthConstraint.h"

@implementation OnePixelWidthConstraint

- (CGFloat)constant {
    return 1./[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}

@end
```

To calculate the value only once:

```
- (CGFloat)constant {
    static CGFloat onePixel = 0;
    return onePixel?:(onePixel = 1./[UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in :

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
   self.separatorHeightConstraint.constant = 0.5f;
   [super updateConstraints];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Type the desired decimal value with a leading 0.

e.g. 0.9,  not .9