# Can't set constraint constant to decimal in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode8

I have constraint for width of view, which I want to set to 0.5, so it could look like a separator. I used to do it before, but now xCode always changes it back to 0. I've tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500448/can-you-enter-a-constraint-value-with-decimal-in-ib), but no luck - it changes back to 0 after I remove focus on field.

Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do that by changing the source code of storyboard directly, without Interface Builder